# How to parse xlsm file without opening it

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to programming, but with most aspects of C#, I've found my way around it. But I'm not finding much online about this and I'm extra scatterbrained today. I just got the whole email section of my program done when I was told I couldnt use a Database to grab the email addresses from, I had to use an Excel doc

I need to read an xlsm and compare username to email to grab the current users email address. I already have the username going in, but haven't found much online that helps with xlsm specifically. Heres a few examples of what Ive tried:

---

This one would be ideal since I like my code short and sweet whenever possible. But when I try to run it, I get 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.' I'm guessing it has to do with using XDocument. Thats how I've been parsing XML files, so I probably have the wrong class here, but again havent found much on xlsm so I'm not sure what to use

```
string[] arr = XDocument.Load(@"C:\example.xlsm").Descendants("Login name" + "Email").Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();
```

---

This one even after downloading OpenXMLSDKV25, it wont find 'DocumentFormat' and filename is already used [const string fileName], but if I change it to fileName2, then it says not all code paths return a value.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;  
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;  
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    public static string GetCellValue(string fileName, string sheetName, string addressName)
    {
        const string fileName = @"C:\example.xlsm";

        // Retrieve the value in cell A1.
        string value = GetCellValue(fileName, "Sheet1", "C2");

        Console.WriteLine(value);

        // Retrieve the date value in cell A2.
        value = GetCellValue(fileName, "Sheet1", "F2");

          Console.WriteLine(DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(value)).ToShortDateString());
    }
```

---

This one doesnt like workbook["Sheet1"] - Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook'

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

        //Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        //Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("example.xlsm");
        //Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook["Sheet1"] as Excel.Worksheet;

        //string someData = (worksheet.Range["C2"] as Excel.Range).Value.ToString();

        //worksheet = null;
        //workbook.Close();
        //excel.Quit();
```

---

Any help would be apprciated!

Comment: The compiler is saying that not all paths in `GetCellValue` return a value, because you don't `return` a value from it.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code (you have to access sheets through the Sheets collection :

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    //Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
    //Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("example.xlsm");
    //Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"] as Excel.Worksheet;

    //string someData = (worksheet.Range["C2"] as Excel.Range).Value.ToString();

    //worksheet = null;
    //workbook.Close();
    //excel.Quit();
```